# How to pin tool options to toolbox in gimp

Tags: gimp

I have somehow disconnected my tool options from my toolbox but when I try to dock my tool options to toolbox using the grab bar and dropping it on the 'you can drop dock able dialog here' box it dosn't attach? please help

Comment: We found that some applications block drag&drop in GIMP - not only for dialog tabs, but also colors and patterns. Among those applications are Kaspersky Antivirus, Camtasia, SnagIt, Camstudio, and Skype.